# Gaussian distribution, Mahlanobis distance, probability

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, mahalanobis

**Suppose we have a set of b variables which have x and y coordinates (bx1 by1, bx2 by2,...,bxN byN) each of which have a gaussian distribution.  we also have somepoints, suppose (Ux1 Uy1, Ux2 Uy2, ....,UxN UyN). Each b variable have a mean, we want to calculate the probability of each point with respect to the means. E.g the probability of point close to a mean (bi) willbe greater than the mean which is far from the point. we can get a matrix with like the one given below, how to get this probability  of U given B as in table mathematically? **